# Undefined method 'default_content_type=' in ActionMailer in Rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I added a system on my project to reset a user's password and send it to him via email in case he forgot it. It was working fine yesterday(when I implemented it). When I tried to fire up the server today, I got the following error.

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/vinayshenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionmailer-3.2.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:437:in `method_missing': undefined method `default_content_type=' for ActionMailer::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
from /Users/vinayshenoy/flo-server/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/vinayshenoy/flo-server/config.ru:4:in `require'
from /Users/vinayshenoy/flo-server/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/vinayshenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/vinayshenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
from /Users/vinayshenoy/flo-server/config.ru:1:in `new'
from /Users/vinayshenoy/flo-server/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
from /Users/vinayshenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
from /Users/vinayshenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /Users/vinayshenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
from /Users/vinayshenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
from /Users/vinayshenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
from /Users/vinayshenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
from /Users/vinayshenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
from /Users/vinayshenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/vinayshenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /Users/vinayshenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

This is my config/environment.rb file

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
FloServer::Application.initialize!

ActionMailer::Base.default_content_type = "text/html"
```

If I comment out the `ActionMailer::Base.default_content_type = "text/html"` line, the server works without any problem. But without it, I can't send emails.

I added this to config/environments/development.rb file yesterday

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port                 => 587,
:user_name            => 'username',
:password             => 'password',
:authentication       => 'plain',
:enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

I've tried restarting the Mac, running "bundle update" and reinstalling rails without any results.

I'm using Rails 3.2.1 on Ruby 1.9.3. Please help.

Comment: default_content_type is not needed. What error do you get when you try sending an email? Also, do you have appropriate view extensions for the email you are trying to send. (action.format.template)

Comment: I've mentioned in the question that the entire system was working fine yesterday. And it wasn't sending the emails until I added that line to environment.rb. I have created view extensions for html but not text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try

```
ActionMailer::Base.default :content_type => "text/html"
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Out of curiosity, any idea why the earlier line was working yesterday, but not today?

Comment: @VinaySShenoy: config options don't get read until server is restarted; you probably had it running yesterday, but had to restart it today, and that's when the changed config was read

Comment: I have this problem too with a bit different so I decided to ask you here instead of asking a new question.
The different of my project is that I add this in Environment.rb :
**config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp | :sendmail | :test**
 How can I handle it? (Thank U!)